# Nothing happens on git pull hook (post-update)

Tags: git, githooks, post-update

when I do a `git pull` on live server I'm logged in as root and so all modified or new files user and group are set to `root:root`.

I've tried this set up in my `post-update` hook file:

```
OWNER="example:example"
REPO_PATH="/home/example/public_html"

cd $REPO_PATH || exit
unset GIT_DIR
FILES="$(git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id)"
git merge FETCH_HEAD

for file in $FILES
    do 
    chown $OWNER $file
done

exec git update-server-info
```

When I run a `git pull` it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: It definitely *shouldn't* do anything, because `git pull` does not invoke a post-update hook.

Comment: doh! So what hook should I use to chown modified of new files after a git pull?

Comment: Consider both `post-checkout` and `post-merge`; see contrib/hooks/setgitperms.perl for a working example.

Comment: @torek if you fancy adding both your comments as a proper answer to this I will gladly mark it complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `git pull` does not invoke the post-update hook: `git pull` is `git fetch` followed by either `git rebase` or `git merge`, more or less, and rebase effectively ends with a `git checkout` while merge is, well, merge.  (For so-called *fast-forward* merges, `git merge` does something much more like `git checkout` internally, but also updates the current branch name.)  Thus, these two hooks are much more appropriate candidates for this kind of work.

Git includes [a `contrib/hooks/setgitperms.perl` example script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/hooks/setgitperms.perl) that's meant to be used in `post-checkout` and `post-merge` hooks.

(It's also worth mentioning that running `git pull` on a live server is not necessarily a good deployment strategy.  Git itself is not a deployment system, and neither push-to-deploy nor pull-to-deploy are adequate by themselves for many real-world setups.  They can work for limited subsets, but in general, consider building or using a real deployment system.)